# how to implement social logins using jwt in node.js backEnd and angular 2 frontEnd

Tags: node.js, angular, jwt

how to implement the social login such as facebook and google authentication 
using Json Web token (jwt) ,same as Auth0 has implemented. i am using node js as back end and angular 2 as front end.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps I'm confused by your phrasing but facebook, google, and JWT are distinct, individual authentication strategies.

But check out [passport.js](http://passportjs.org/) it offers hundreds of authentication strategies:

defined strategy: (this example uses mongoose)

```
const jwtOptions = {
  jwtFromRequest: PJWT.ExtractJwt.fromAuthHeader(),
  secretOrKey: SECRET, // externally defined private encryption key
}

export const jwtStrategy = new PJWT.Strategy(jwtOptions,
  function (jwt_payload, done) {
    MongoUser.findOne({ email: jwt_payload.email }, function (err, user) { // presumes the user's email is in the jwt
      if (err) return done(err, false);
      if (user) return done(null, user);
      else return done(null, false);
    });
  });
```

also these are needed by passport:

```
type Done = (err: any, user?: {}) => void;

export const serializeMongoUser = function (user: UserDoc, done: Done) {
  done(null, user._id);
}

export const deserializeMongoUser = function (_id: any, done: Done) {
  MongoUser.findById(_id, function (err, user) {
    done(err, user);
  });
}
```

add the middleware to your server:

```
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());
passport.serializeUser(ppt.serializeMongoUser);
passport.deserializeUser(ppt.deserializeMongoUser);
passport.use(ppt.jwtStrategy);
```

authenticate from a service in your app:

```
  authenticate(): Observable<any> {
    if (!this.security.jwt) return Observable.of({sucess: false})
    return this.http.get('/api/authenticate', authHeaders(this.security))
      .map(res => res.json());
  }
```

call this function when you need to authenticate:

*note the `authHeaders(this.security)`

`this.security` is a subscription to the JWT token in my `ngrx` store, but you could also put it in [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage).

```
export function authHeaders(security: Security) {
  const headers = new Headers();
  headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json; charset=utf-8');
  headers.append('Authorization', `JWT ${security.jwt}`);
  return { headers };
}
```

calling `authenticate()` will return `{success: true}` or `{success: false}`

Answer (score 0):

Here is a little example I created to show the basics of socket.io security with JWT authentication. The backend is nodeJS, socket.io, and express.

In the long run you should use passport for user sessions but the below is good to see so you get the whole picture.

#### Overview

When browsing to http://127.0.0.1:3001, the express middleware `socketAuthenticated` will create a jwt based on the hard coated user credentials (should use passport sessions for real user info).

This token is then passed to the server EJS view and used to establish a socket connection.

1. Create a new folder for the app and run `npm install express socketio-jwt jsonwebtoken ejs-locals socket.io`
2. Create a "public" folder within the root folder and put the socket.io-client JS file inside (you can run `bower install socket.io-client` to get the js file)
3. Create `app.js` file within the root folder with the following:

   ```
   let express = require('express'),
   socketioJwt = require('socketio-jwt'),
   jwt = require('jsonwebtoken'),
   port = 3001
   engine = require('ejs-locals');

   let app = express();

   let socketAuthenticated = (req, res, next) => {
   let token = jwt.sign({firstName:"jason", lastName:"owl"}, "secret", { expiresIn: 60*5 }); // assuming you have some user object in req
        res.token = token; // front end will use this token to authenticate its socket connection
       next();
    };

   app.engine('ejs', engine);
   app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
   app.set('view options', {defaultLayout: 'layout'});
   app.use(express.static('public'));
   app.use(socketAuthenticated);

    app.route('/')
        .get((req, res) => {
            console.log(`Server Passing Token: ${res.token} to client`);
            res.render('index', { jwt: res.token });
        });

    let server = require('http').Server(app);
    let io = require('socket.io')(server);

    // Setup socket server to use JWT
    io.set('authorization', socketioJwt.authorize({
        secret: "secret",
        handshake: true
    }));

   io.of('/default').on('connection', (socket) => {
       socket.on('data', (newConfig) => {
            console.log('Data Event Recieved!');
       });
   });


   server.listen(port);

   console.log(`\Application: ${process.pid} Listening On Port: ${port}`);
   ```

4) Create a new folder called views and create a file called `index.ejs`:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/socket.io.js"></script>
<script>

    var jwttoken = <%- JSON.stringify(jwt) %>;

    function connect_socket (token) {
      var socket = io.connect('/default', {
        query: 'token=' + token
      });
      return socket;
    }

    var socket = connect_socket(jwttoken);
    socket.emit('data');
</script>
```

5. run `node app.js` and open the browser to localhost:3001.